# Parts of external Javascript not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

This is pretty simple but I can't figure out why only some parts of the Javascript execute and others don't. My html file is just a (div) and I want the javascript to change the colors of the (div) when the mouse hovers over it and then back to normal after leaving it.

The html file is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Button Magic</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript file. It's saved as script.js and to test if it was even executing, I created an alert to comes up, and it does, so it must be a problem below that I cannot see.

```
alert("test"); 

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
$('div').fadeTo("fast",1);
});

$('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $('div').fadeTo("fast",0.5);

});
});
```

Comment: *"I want the javascript to change the colors of the (div) when the mouse hovers over it and then back to normal after leaving it."* what is it doing instead?

Comment: I'm curious: What's the opacity of the div by default? Because you're using a `fadeTo` when the mouse enters. Does it start out 0.5? Why?

Comment: The div isn't changing at all when I hover my mouse over it. The div's original opacity is set to .5 on my .css file, so it should darken to 1 once the mouse hovers over it and then return to normal.

Comment: I was learning how to code on codecademy.com and this was one of the exercises. If anyone is a member of it, this is on Lesson 3, exercise 4. Their program shows the div changing with these lines of code yet I can't get it to work 'for real'.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually included jQuery, so all of the jQuery code is failing.

Add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before the other `script` tag.

Comment: I just entered this right before my other script tag, refreshed my .html file, but all that did was add another div directly underneath the original one. Am I missing something?

Comment: Apparently... although if this is just a local file (not loading from a server), you'll need to use `http://ajax...` instead of `//ajax...` to load jQuery.  Still, hard to say without seeing the updated code.

Comment: With jQuery in place, your code seems to do roughly the opposite of what you wanted: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/nreIf

Comment: Their was a second div in the code so that was my fault. And I used codepen and can get it to work on that website so I am confused why it won't work outside of that..

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you guys. You were right. This was the first time I had ever seen 'ajax' referenced before. I can't even vote up your answer because I don't have 15 rep points. lol. UP VOTE.